# #include Windows.h inside of DLL file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to create a color dialog DLL inside of C++ using the ChooseColor. Although every time I build I get the issue

```
1>ChooseColorDLL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChooseColorA referenced in function "void __cdecl ShowMyDialog(char *)" (?ShowMyDialog@@YAXPEAD@Z)
```

Here is my .cpp file inside my DLL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ChooseColorDLL.h"
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

CHOOSECOLORDLL_API void ShowDialog(char* i)
{

    static COLORREF  colorrefCustomColours[16] = {0} ;
    CHOOSECOLOR cc;

    cc.hwndOwner = NULL;    //No Owner
    cc.hInstance = NULL;
    cc.rgbResult =    RGB(0,0,0);
    cc.lpfnHook =NULL;
    cc.Flags = CC_SOLIDCOLOR | CC_PREVENTFULLOPEN;
    cc.lpCustColors = colorrefCustomColours;
    cc.lpTemplateName = NULL;
    cc.lCustData = NULL;
    cc.lStructSize = sizeof(cc);
    // Seperate Colors
    ChooseColor(&cc);
}
```

ChooseColorDLL.h:

```
#ifdef CHOOSECOLORDLL_EXPORTS
#define CHOOSECOLORDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CHOOSECOLORDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

CHOOSECOLORDLL_API void ShowDialog(char* i);
```

Comment: As in it doesn't recognize ChooseColor() as a function. it is underlined as undefined

Comment: You're still being vague. Is `ChooseColor()` not recognized within the DLL, or within some client code that's trying to use the DLL? If it's the latter, the client code needs to include `Windows.h` also.

Comment: "I am having issues with" is pretty meaningless unless you explain what "issues" are. Do you get a compiler error? If so, what **exactly** is the error message? If it's not a compiler error, is it something else? You need to be *specific* in your questions here, because we can't see your screen or read your mind. You need to provide the information to us to use to help you. The function and #DEFINEs you're using are actually in `CommDlg.h`, so I suspect you've forgotten to define something prior to including Windows.h

Comment: The actual DLL does not recognize `ChooseColor()` @Praetorian

Comment: @user1334858 Can you please copy-paste the exact error message? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) including `Windows.h` should work.

Comment: There is no obvious problem with this code.  What users are telling you here is to not just *talk* about the error messages but actually copy/paste them into your question.  Only the first two messages are important, the rest of them are usually junk messages, caused by the first few errors.  With the obvious risk that you told us about the junk messages and forgot the important ones.

Comment: Here is the error `1>ChooseColorDLL.cpp(15): error C2065: 'CHOOSECOLOR' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: It is not a build error it has to do with `ChooseColor()` not being recognized as a function, along with the other ones not being recognized as identifiers. There is nothing else wrong with the code. If it could recognize the function there would be no errors. When built the first error is that `CHOOSECOLOR` is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: That is a build error, since it happens at build time.

Comment: @MariusBancila I just added the header file.

Comment: Mispelled variable and function names are a pet peeve of mine. The function should be spelled `ShowDialog`, but should be named something a bit more descriptive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking error to ChooseColor() when creating DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965947/linking-error-to-choosecolor-when-creating-dll)

Answer (score 3):

I'm reasonably sure that the problem is that your build doesn't set the WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT versions are either not set, or not set correctly - see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx)

In other words, before `#include <windows.h>`, you should have:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

By default, so that apps work on "ANY" version of Windows, the windows.h only gives you functions that are available in EVERY version of windows from WinNT4 and onwards. Since this is introduced in Win2K, it isn't default. The above define gives you Win2K variants. Other values are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I just tired this, but it did not work. I still have the same errors when it built. I mean my test project when I tested this function was able to set WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT correctly.

Comment: And you added this BEFORE the #include of windows.h? And `stdafx.h` doesn't include `windows.h`? or `ChooseColorDLL.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Look up ChooseColor in MSDN. In the "Requirements" section of that page it says you must link to ComDlg32.lib.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646912(v=vs.85).aspx

Failing to link to the required lib typically produces the 'unresolved external symbol' error.